# How to fetch structured API data to HTML (JSON.parse?)

Tags: javascript, json, api

I've been working on a website that has to show data retrieved from an API, but I'm not that familiar with Javascript. Even after following some tutorials and looking up other topics on Stack Overflow, I don't seem to understand the logic. So I hope that anyone here could help me.

Right now I am pulling data from specified API's, for example:

```
$.get( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=EUR",
    function( data ) {
        $( '#btcwaarde' ).text( data["EUR"] );
    }
);
```

This actually works, but only for retrieving 1 piece of data per API request. What I would like to do, is retrieve data from a bigger piece of JSON data, for example: from [a result like this](https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH,LTC,XRP&tsyms=EUR).

To do that I need to understand which function I should use and the array logic. I've also taken a look at `JSON.parse` but I don't really understand how it works.

Could anyone please explain this to me or give me an example that I can use to further build the code?

**EDIT:** What I would like to achieve, is to display the data in an HTML element on my website. So the HTML will be something like:

```
<div class="element">
     <span id="BTCprice"></span>
     <span id="BTCmktcap"></span>
</div>
<div class="element">
    <span id="ETHprice"></span>
    <span id="ETHmktcap"></span>
</div>
```

The unique `<span>`s then have to display the data pulled from the API relevant to the `<span>`.

For example `#BTCprice` has to show the info from `[DISPLAY][BTC][EUR][PRICE]` while `#ETHmktcap` has to show the info from `[DISPLAY][ETH][EUR][MKTCAP]`.

Comment: You haven't said what you are trying to achieve. That makes it difficult to help. It does sound like you really should just read an introductory JavaScript tutorial. Basic processing of arrays and objects is very basic stuff that any introductory guide should cover.

Comment: "I've also taken a look at JSON.parse" — jQuery is calling it behind the scenes. That's why your first example worked.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have just added info about what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

After OP's edit. More complex sollution:

```
$(function() {

 $.get( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH,LTC,XRP&tsyms=EUR", function( data ) {
  $.each(data['DISPLAY'], function( index, value ) {

    var spanPrice = $('<span/>')
        .attr('id', index+"price")
        .html(value['EUR']['PRICE']);

    var spanMktcap = $('<span/>')
        .attr('id', index+"mktcap")
        .html(value['EUR']['MKTCAP']);

    var $newDiv = $("<div/>")   // creates a div element
        .attr("id", index)  // adds the id
        .addClass("element")   // add a class
        .append(spanPrice)
        .append(spanMktcap)

         $("code").append($newDiv);
  });
});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d3gzz6x1/

Comment: Thanks! This works but it now display info about every array item in the paragraph. What if I would like to specify that it only loads ['BTC'] for example?

Comment: Just directly access an array elem:
`$.get( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH,LTC,XRP&tsyms=EUR", function( data ) {
    $('#btcwaarde').text(data['DISPLAY']['BTC']['EUR']['PRICE']);
});`

Answer (score 0):

## Object access

**The following was posted before a question update; see the answer updates farther below:**

Without knowing **exactly** how you want to access the data, it is difficult to provide an answer that shows you *exactly* what you're looking to achieve.

But basically, [an `object` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) has a `key: value` structure, which can be accessed [in many different ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), and which way to use depends on the circumstances.

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
  if ( req.readyState === 4 ) {
    if ( req.status === 200 ) {
      var rt = req.responseText, // this is a string
          json = JSON.parse( rt ); // parse the string to an object
      // access the object values
      console.log( json[ "RAW" ][ "BTC" ][ "EUR" ][ "TYPE" ] );
      // or
      console.log( json.RAW.BTC.EUR.TYPE );
    } else if ( req.status ) {
      console.warn( req.status );
    } else {
      console.error( "Danger Will Robinson!" );
    }
  }
}, false );
req.open( "GET", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH,LTC,XRP&tsyms=EUR", true );
req.setRequestHeader( "Accept", "application/json" );
req.send();
```

### Updates (as mentioned above)

You've got a couple of options here; you can either populate hard-coded HTML or dynamically create new HTML as required.

**Population**

Since the HTML elements are already in place, you'd do well to have a map to them that tells you what to fill them with. This could be more dynamic than demonstrated by changing the element `id`s to more closely resemble the path(s) through the `json` to the data, but for a simple demo:

```js
function updateHTML( json ) {
  const lookup = function( id ) {
      return { "BTCprice":  json.DISPLAY.BTC.EUR.PRICE,
               "BTCmktcap": json.DISPLAY.BTC.EUR.MKTCAP,
               "ETHprice":  json.DISPLAY.ETH.EUR.PRICE,
               "ETHmktcap": json.DISPLAY.ETH.EUR.MKTCAP
               // etc.
      }[ id ] || "Unknown";
    },
    spans = document.querySelectorAll( "span[id]" );
  spans.forEach( function( v ) {
    v.textContent = lookup( v.id );
  } );
}

function requestStuff( addr ) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest(), sts;
  req.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
    if ( req.readyState === 4 ) {
      sts = req.status;
      if ( sts === 200 ) {
        updateHTML( JSON.parse( req.responseText ) );
      } else if ( sts ) {
        console.warn( sts );
      } else {
        console.error( "Danger Will Robinson!" );
      }
   }
  }, false );
  req.open( "GET", addr, true );
  req.setRequestHeader( "Accept", "application/json" );
  req.send();
}

requestStuff( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH,LTC,XRP&tsyms=EUR" );
```

```css
span:before {
    content: attr( id ) ": ";
}
span:first-child:after {
    content: ", ";
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
     <span id="BTCprice"></span>
     <span id="BTCmktcap"></span>
</div>
<div class="element">
    <span id="ETHprice"></span>
    <span id="ETHmktcap"></span>
</div>
```

**Dynamic creation**

This would be a very similar process as above, but instead of mapping to already existent HTML, we build it as needed, using an object of nested arrays as the map of what to build and with what we fill it.

```js
function updateHTML( json ) {
  const props = {
    "BTC": [ [ "BTCprice",  json.DISPLAY.BTC.EUR.PRICE ],
             [ "BTCmktcap", json.DISPLAY.BTC.EUR.MKTCAP ] ],
    "ETH": [ [ "ETHprice",  json.DISPLAY.ETH.EUR.PRICE ],
             [ "ETHmktcap", json.DISPLAY.ETH.EUR.MKTCAP ] ]
    };
  var prop, div, span;
  for ( prop in props ) {
    if ( props.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
      div = document.createElement( "div" );
      props[ prop ].forEach( function( v ) {
        span = document.createElement( "span" );
        span.textContent = v[ 1 ];
        span.id = v [ 0 ];
        div.appendChild( span );
      } );
      document.body.appendChild( div );
    }
  }
}

function requestStuff( addr ) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest(), sts;
  req.addEventListener( "readystatechange", function() {
    if ( req.readyState === 4 ) {
      sts = req.status;
      if ( sts === 200 ) {
        updateHTML( JSON.parse( req.responseText ) );
      } else if ( sts ) {
        console.warn( sts );
      } else {
        console.error( "Danger Will Robinson!" );
      }
   }
  }, false );
  req.open( "GET", addr, true );
  req.setRequestHeader( "Accept", "application/json" );
  req.send();
}

requestStuff( "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC,ETH,DASH,LTC,XRP&tsyms=EUR" );
```

```css
span:before {
    content: attr( id ) ": ";
}
span:first-child:after {
    content: ", ";
}
```

### Why aren't the demos written in jQuery?

As you (the OP) stated in the question:

> I'm not that familiar with Javascript. Even after following some tutorials and looking up other topics on Stack Overflow, I don't seem to understand the logic.

As [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is a JavaScript library, to better understand how to use it, you should first have a basic understanding of [*vanilla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) JavaScript.

DOM manipulation, reading and writing data to and from arrays and objects, making asynchronous HTTP requests *etc.* is the backbone of JS.

I wrote the demos in JavaScript to better show what is actually happening.

Learn and use jQuery once you **are** familiar with JS.